# Cannot figure out Crashlytics report

Tags: ios, debugging, crashlytics

Basically I have this displayed in my Crashlytics report.
This error crashes the app.
It doesn't show any line of code I written and Google search doesn't help either.

Below are screenshots.
Both are showing the same thing just different ways of showing data.

http://postimg.org/image/4k9hb3sbx/

http://postimg.org/image/c2xgd2lqv/

UPDATE:

found that this was related to this bug here [NSRangeException on iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878621/nsrangeexception-on-ios-8/30003347#30003347)

Comment: set an excpetion breakpoint, then the execution will stop where the exception occurs. but anywhere in your code you are trying to remove an object from an array at index 4 but the array has only 4 elements(index 0 to 3).

Comment: well there is always a catch... the problem is I cannot replicate the bug at all. The users keep reporting problem and I cannot reproduce it even when they gave me access to their accounts.
The only difference I can see for now is iOS version (I have 8.1.3 and one of the users has 8.3) I'm still collecting data for others.

Comment: so update your device :-) and try to reproduce

Comment: in moments like these clarity has a hard time finding me :)
thanks for the advice... will do that

Comment: installed the new version and now the app crashes like crazy :)  Thank you very much!!!!